# How can I import a txt file with both tsv and csv characteristics and plot it?

Tags: import, csv-format, tsv-format

I have a problem with importing and plotting a txt data.

I used this code:

***data=Import["C:/Users/user/Desktop/Mohammad Simulation/2nm.txt","TSV"]
header=Take[data, {10, 1889}];***

But, I am not able to have a table to ListPlot the result.
I am attaching the txt fie.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How can I add the txt file or you may help and answer me with your own txt file?

Comment: Put it in some file sharing account like Drop Box, Google Drive, or some other and edit your post to include the link.

Comment: Or post a sample here. Usually a few rows and columns of a CSV-like file is enough to create a proof of concept for how to import it.

Comment: @Edmund  A part of the .text file which can be used is this:           
% Date:               May 5 2020, 17:54
% Nodes:              1880
% Expressions:        1
% Description:        Magnetic field norm
% Length unit:        m
% x                       y                        mef.normH (A/m)
1.0E-8                    0                        104.27008000876057
1.0E-8                    1.6666666667111697E-8    104.27010185658986
1.0E-8                    3.3333333334223394E-8    104.27016724623279
1.0E-8                    5.000000000133509E-8     104.27027618297726

Comment: This is the linke of the .txt file:       https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/newmytest4/2nm.txt